# How to run vbs file in php

Tags: php, vbscript

i have a VBScript file. When its on the computer it works fine. I want to put it on a php site for it to be executed by a button click. can it run in php?

thanks.

Comment: uh, maybe? you don't say ANYTHING about "a php site". is it a windows box? If not, then vbscript is HIGHLY likely to be anything but random text garbage for that machine.

Comment: i just want to run "a.vbs" using php file and i have looking the solution in forum, wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is

system('cscript.exe "C:/somedir/somevbsfile.vbs"');

Answer (score 1):

1)Put you VBS code inside a file for example : `"my_vbs_code.vbs"`

2)You need to have the extension `"COM"` **enabled** in you `PHP config`.

3)Within your PHP script write this code :

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$obj = $WshShell->Run("cscript ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/my_vbs_code.vbs", 0, true);
```

Comment: i have try it, but i cant get response..
my "com" extension is already enabled.
if i want to show the window of $wshshell i have to replace "0" with "1", isn't it? but i still didnt get the response..
what should i do to get information about script is running?
sorry, my english not good :D

Answer (score 0):

Found this gem: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx

By that, you should try the similar in PHP:

exec('wscript "C:/path/to/script.vbs"');